# PayPal PHP API - Create an order to multiple merchants and pay once

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

i need to implement an e-commerce website, that contains multiple objects to purchase, but they can belong to different merchants.

Once the user chooses more then one object, that belongs to different merchants, I need to create more then one order to merchants, but the user must pay once.

At the moment, I'm using the following php github repository:

https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-PHP-SDK

It seems to work fine, but I'm not able to create multiple orders to different merchants, and let the user to pay only one time.

Is there a way to implement the above request?

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't; the checkout to each receiver must be separate.

The APIs and checkout flows that used to be able to do that type of checkout (EC Parallel Payments and Adaptive Payments) are old and deprecated. Do not use them.